Use dynamic table name in Join with Gorm to add WITH(NOLOCK)
I'm using gorm in my golang project to connect a SQL Server database and everything works fine.
Now I would like to dynamically set the table name in my Joins() calls, like I can do with the main (model) table as the docs explains.
My goal is to add the " WITH(NOLOCK)" sql command after the table while building the statement.
Actual code:
// Adds WITH(NOLOCK) to the model table defined by calling Model()
func WithNoLock() func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {

    if tabler, ok := tx.Statement.Model.(schema.Tabler); ok {
      return tx.Table(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\" WITH(NOLOCK)", tabler.TableName()))
    } else {
      return tx
    }

  }
}


func MyQuery(id int) (MyModel, error) {

  var result MyModel //Has "ID" PK and "OtherTable" FK correctly set

  err := r.DB().Model(&result).
    Joins("OtherTable").
    Scopes(WithNoLock()).
    Take(&result, id).
    Error

  return result, err
}

Produces something like SELECT ... FROM MyModel WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN OtherTable ON ... and so on.
The goal is SELECT ... FROM MyModel WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN OtherTable WITH(NOLOCK) ON ... without using raw SQL or injecting the join manually like Joins("JOIN OtherTable WITH(NOLOCK) ON ...")

I would ask, why do you want to add NOLOCK in the first place? It's (almost) always a bad idea. Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere

We (my colleagues and I) know all the downsides of NOLOCK, we are not going to improperly use it. Unfortunately we have some very old bad managed tables that we can't fix (for now) and we need to perform some queries with NOLOCK

"we are not going to improperly use it." I would suggest otherwise, based on these requirements; if you wanted NOLOCK against one table, I'd maybe accept it, but against every table is clear abuse.

It's not on every table, it's just two. And I would like to join them. Should I change the question to "How can I change the table name in a join"? The point here is not the NOLOCK, we already know when, where and how to use NOLOCK.
